# How do I empty the recycle bin on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

Where have they hidden the recycle bin?

Comment: ok... i found it on the desktop, but where is it really?

Comment: Why do you need to know? Just right click on the icon and select the empty option.

Answer (score 4):

Each drive shows the recycle bin in windows 7, and it's a hidden folder called $Recycle.Bin ...although it shows up on each drive, there's really just one bin, all the drives are 'shortcuts' to the same bin. Right-click, empty really does fully empty it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the Recycle Bin on my desktop, and it took me some time to understand how to empty it:

1. Open the Windows Explorer
2. Go in Computer
3. Right click on the disk whose you want to empty the Recycle Bin, and click on Properties
4. Click on Disk Cleanup
5. Tick the Recycle Bin checkbox, click on Ok.

That's it!

Comment: In the general case of using Windows, the Recycle Bin is present on the desktop.  In Windows 7, you can hide/unhide by clicking Start and searching for "Show or hide common icons on the desktop".

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Ow, maybe I disabled it and forgot it. I do not like to have things on the desktop because it it difficult to access them: I must minimize the window, do the thing, and re-display the window. I prefer the Start launcher; I put all I can in it. I searched "Recycle" in the launcher, but there is no result.

Answer (score -2):

Right click in file explorer left side panel. Click show all folders. Right click recycle bin once it appears. Empty it